# Image size during training in yolov5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to train a custom dataset in yolov5.
So I am trying to run it with an image size of 640x480 but it is not working.

python3  /YOLOv5/yolov5/train.py --img-size 640 480 --batch 8 --epochs 300 --data data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache

```
    usage: train.py [-h] [--weights WEIGHTS] [--cfg CFG] [--data DATA] [--hyp HYP] [--epochs EPOCHS]
                [--batch-size BATCH_SIZE] [--imgsz IMGSZ] [--rect] [--resume [RESUME]] [--nosave]
                [--noval] [--noautoanchor] [--noplots] [--evolve [EVOLVE]] [--bucket BUCKET]
                [--cache [CACHE]] [--image-weights] [--device DEVICE] [--multi-scale]
                [--single-cls] [--optimizer {SGD,Adam,AdamW}] [--sync-bn] [--workers WORKERS]
                [--project PROJECT] [--name NAME] [--exist-ok] [--quad] [--cos-lr]
                [--label-smoothing LABEL_SMOOTHING] [--patience PATIENCE]
                [--freeze FREEZE [FREEZE ...]] [--save-period SAVE_PERIOD]
                [--local_rank LOCAL_RANK] [--entity ENTITY] [--upload_dataset [UPLOAD_DATASET]]
                [--bbox_interval BBOX_INTERVAL] [--artifact_alias ARTIFACT_ALIAS]
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 480
```

def parse_opt(known=False):
parser.add_argument('--imgsz', '--img', '--img-size', type=int, default=640, help='train, val image size (pixels)')
(https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git)

Comment: try 640,480 instead of 640 480

Comment: train.py: error: argument --imgsz/--img/--img-size: invalid int value: '640,480'

Comment: After taking a look at the source code, the argument for image size accepts `int` only, this means the width and height of input images are equals.

Answer (score 0):

```
--img-size
```

only takes one argument. Use:

```
python3 /YOLOv5/yolov5/train.py --img-size 640 --batch 8 --epochs 300 --data data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache
```

the height of the image will be adjusted accordingly, respecting the aspect ratio and stride needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify as below:

```
--imgsz 480 640
```

This works for me.